# shiny: How to update a reactiveValues object?

Tags: r, shiny

I have a pair of auxiliary inputs that allows user to choose combinations from a set of choices. Also, it is convenient one to be able to remove an item that was created before.

For this task, a named list, in the form of reactiveValues object, `listN <- reactiveValues()`, will be in charge to store these information.

The function to ADD items is working like a charm, but when I try to REMOVE items from `listN`, its item names persists forever!

My strategy was make use of `reactiveValuesToList()`, manipulate its items and replace `listN` with a brand new instance of `reactiveValues()` (or `do.call(reactiveValues, listN_as_list)`.

I stored a reproducible app at Gist. I hope it is sufficient to you guys help me out. Please insist in more clarification if needed.

URL:

[gist.github.com/d43e72959c4576d27535](http://gist.github.com/d43e72959c4576d27535)

Code to run on console:

`shiny::runGist('d43e72959c4576d27535')`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Didn't try the solution, but isn't it an scoping issue? Maybe use `<<-` instead of `<-` somewhere.

Comment: I tried it already, no luck. =(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answer from Joe Cheng at [Shiny Google Groups:](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/shiny-discuss/7TW5OchNjc8)

> Yeah, you can't replace an entire reactiveValues instance like that
>   and expect anything that's bound to the previous reactiveValues
>   instance to instantly know about the new one. The slots on the
>   reactiveValues instance itself are reactive, but its own variable is
>   not.
>
> I think the real issue here is that, unlike lists and envs, you can't
>   remove values from reactiveValues, only set them to NULL.
>
> There are two easy workarounds I can think of:
>
> 1) In addition to the `reactiveValues` instance's slots being reactive, also make the variable
>   reactive, using makeReactiveBinding.
>
> 2) You could also use reactiveValues
>   as normal, but keep a list IN the reactiveValues that holds the
>   combinations, not having the reactiveValues itself hold the values. In
>   other words, `values <- reactiveValues(combos = list())`, and when
>   something new gets added, `values$combos[[x]] <- y`.
>
> In trying out fix
>   number 1 above, I found that updateSelectInput doesn't work properly when choices is a length-0 vector. Instead of sending a 0-length vector to
>   the client, it doesn't send anything for choices at all, so the
>   choices never change.
>
> I've forked your gist and added two revisions: one that implements
>   workaround #1 (along with some other problems I found), and one that
>   works around the updateSelectInput issue by using renderUI.
>   https://gist.github.com/jcheng5/eaedfed5095d37217fca/revisions