# R Shiny - reset/delete a table created within "eventReactive({ })"

Tags: r, shiny

I want to reset a table that is created using eventReactive. This is a simple example below. First button to upload a csv, Second a button eventReactive to create a table, the reset button i'm trying to make work is to delete the table (not the output). I know I can reset/delete the output using RenderUI(Null), but the descriptivetable will still there (but not visible). Is there a way to reset/delete this table?

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput("file1", "Choose CSV File", accept = ".csv"),
      actionButton('Calculate_DS', 'Calculate Descriptive Statistics'),
      actionButton('Reset_Button', 'Reset Descriptive Statistics'),
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tableOutput("contents_DS"),
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  df_from_raw <- reactive({ 
    file <- input$file1
    req(file)
    read.csv(file$datapath ) 
  })
  descriptivetable <-  eventReactive( input$Calculate_DS,{
    df <- df_from_raw()
    Descriptive_base <- data.frame(Variable= names( Filter(is.numeric, df) ),
                                   N = sapply( Filter(is.numeric, df), function(x) sum(!is.na(x))),
                                   Minimum = round( sapply( Filter(is.numeric, df) , min, na.rm=TRUE) ,2) ,
                                   Maximum = round( sapply( Filter(is.numeric, df) , max, na.rm=TRUE) ,2),
                                   Sum = format( round( sapply( Filter(is.numeric, df) , sum, na.rm=TRUE) ,2), scientific=F),
                                   Mean = format( round( sapply( Filter(is.numeric, df) , mean, na.rm=TRUE) ,2), scientific=F) )
    return( Descriptive_base )
  })
  output$contents_DS <- renderTable( {  descriptivetable()   } , caption="Descriptive Statistics", caption.placement = "top"  )
  
  # This is the part of the code I can't get to reset/delete the table
  observeEvent(input$Reset_Button, {
    df_from_raw <- NULL
    df <- NULL
    descriptivetable <- NULL
    Descriptive_base <- NULL
    # output$contents_DS <- renderUI(NULL) # this would remove the ouput but I want the descriptivetable reset/deleted
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently it's not possible to reset the reactive event. However there is a workaround. You can create a list of `reactiveValues`. And set the respective element in the list to `NULL`. as noted here:

[How to reset reactiveValues?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61887112/how-to-reset-reactivevalues)

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
        sidebarLayout(
                sidebarPanel(
                        fileInput("file1", "Choose CSV File", accept = ".csv"),
                        actionButton('Calculate_DS', 'Calculate Descriptive Statistics'),
                        actionButton('Reset_Button', 'Reset Descriptive Statistics'),
                ),
                mainPanel(
                        tableOutput("contents_DS"),
                )
        )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
        #Workaround starts here: Create reactive value in list
        Descriptive_base  <- reactiveValues("df" = list())
        
        df_from_raw <- reactive({
                file <- input$file1
                req(file)
                read.csv(file$datapath)
        })
        
        observe({
                df <- df_from_raw()
                Descriptive_base$df <-
                        data.frame(Variable= names( Filter(is.numeric, df) ),
                                   N = sapply( Filter(is.numeric, df), function(x) sum(!is.na(x))),
                                   Minimum = round( sapply( Filter(is.numeric, df) , min, na.rm=TRUE) ,2) ,
                                   Maximum = round( sapply( Filter(is.numeric, df) , max, na.rm=TRUE) ,2),
                                   Sum = format( round( sapply( Filter(is.numeric, df) , sum, na.rm=TRUE) ,2), scientific=F),
                                   Mean = format( round( sapply( Filter(is.numeric, df) , mean, na.rm=TRUE) ,2), scientific=F) )
        }) |> bindEvent(input$Calculate_DS)
        
        output$contents_DS <-
                renderTable({
                        Descriptive_base$df
                } , caption = "Descriptive Statistics", caption.placement = "top")
        
        # Now you can reset the reactive value
        observe({
                Descriptive_base$df <- NULL
        }) |> bindEvent(input$Reset_Button)
        
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: This is really useful, I need to learn more about this method. It doesn't feel very intuitive though. It seems "descriptivetable" is no longer used. I need to read up more about "reactivevalues" and "observe". Many thanks

Comment: I'm using a code to download  
downloadHandler( filename = function(){"Descriptive Statistics.csv"}, content = function(fname){ write.csv(descriptivetable(), fname ,  row.names=FALSE, na="")     }   ) . Do you know what I need to change "descriptivetable()" to ? Do i use "Descriptive_base$df"?

Comment: Yes, my bad! descriptivetable is not used anymore. Forgot to remove it. Let me update it real quick.
`bindEvent` is also a very useful function! :)

Comment: Changing descriptivetable() to Descriptive_base$df in the download handler should work. Let me know if it's not working.

Comment: That works perfectly. Before when I was just resetting the UI, it could still download the table. This reset of the table, means it can't be downloaded, perfect! many thanks for all your help